# How do I programatically create a node, add a menu item, and add a path alias?

Tags: nodes, 6

I am using Drupal 6. I have an external database that I need to somehow turn into nodes so that our Drupal site can display the content and search the content with Solr. I currently have a module which displays pages and queries the database directly each time these pages are viewed. This is not an optimal solution because these pages are not found when a user uses our search.

I know that I can iterate through the database items, create a $node object and use node_save() to create nodes.

1) Can I set a specific NID such as $node->nid = 9999999 . $some_database_key so that I know these nodes can be referenced later for updating?

**I could not get this to work, but I did figure out this solution:**
I created a database table for my module similar to the one in the node_example module. Using this and a custom content type, I could create nodes. I could not get it to work properly until I used

```
$node = node_submit($node);
```

prior to calling

```
node_save($node);
```

2) How do I create menu items for these new nodes?

**Solution**

```
$link = array();
$link['menu_name'] = 'custom_menu'; // Fill out your menu name or just use navigation
$link['link_title'] = 'Title Here'; // What appears in the menu link
$link['link_path'] = 'node/' . $node->nid; // Or you can use a path alias as well
$link['plid'] = 12; // Optional - if you want it to nest under an item you'll need its mlid (menu id)
menu_link_save($link);
```

See: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/6

3) How do I create aliases for these nodes such as node/856 goes to programs/some-program-type/some-program-title

**SOLUTION**
Similar to the menu solution above, you can use

```
path_set_alias('node/' . $node->nid, 'path/alias/here');
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Here's a really old one regarding drupal 5: http://www.unibia.com/unibianet/drupal/how-create-drupal-nodes-script

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to add your specific solutions to the question.  You mirror an issue I'm currently having.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have some external database, and your nodes are in relation with some entities from there. You need node 'downloading' some content from other database; for compatibility with Solr.

1) Instead 'hacking' node number, I think you should use create node type for it. Beside distinguishing downloaded nodes for others; you can create CCK field for storing external database id; and setting content edition permission that nobody can edit it.

2) In your custom module you need to implement hook_blocks to put in the menu content that you need.

3) With [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module you can simply create automatic path. If you create special content type out of the box pathauto functionality should be enough.